# Which is better between WPS and LibreOffice?

Tags: wps-office

I recently installed Ubuntu on my computer and I have a problem choosing the office software. Before, the software I used on the Windows system was WPS Office, but after browsing the English community, I found that people basically use LibreOffice. I have tried to use LibreOffice, but it seems to have more problems with the file format than WPS, so I want to know which of the two software is better.
The format problem refers to its compatibility with Microsoft Office. Sometimes files edited by these two software cannot be displayed correctly by Microsoft Office, or files generated by Microsoft Office cannot be displayed properly by these two softwares. This is a difficult problem to get around. And what I need most is compatibility. If the files I hand over to the superior cannot be displayed normally, it will be a serious problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking.  What "problems with the file format" are you referring to?  Libreoffice is available from the Ubuntu repository and is installed by default.  I guess that might be the reason why it is favoured by the Ubuntu community.  "Which one is better" is a subjective question -- if there was one clear answer, then one of the two would have disappeared from the market.  As both exist, then clearly some people think one is better; others think the other is.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please read the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for what questions are allowed. Opinion based questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Neither office productivity suite is better. Which office productivity suite is better for you depends on your use case. There is such a large amount of functionality in both LibreOffice and WPS, that it is likely that you will only use small subset of the features of either, however you will not stick with an office productivity suite that doesn't have the features and functionality that you need. Try both LibreOffice and WPS and see which one works better for you.